# Angular Function returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello I find myself confused as to why my console log is coming back undefined in Angular.  Im am trying to display data on a card in html. The plan was to wire whatever data was coming in and display it through cardValue

Service.ts

```
 incomingData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('this_is_incoming_data/', {});
  }
```

Component.ts

```
cardDetails = [
    {
     cardValue: console.log('this is test 3, 'this.custom()),
    }


returnedData: any;

ngOnInit(): any {
  this.Service.incomingData().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.returnedData = data;
    console.log('test1',this.returnedData);
    this.custom();
  });
} 


custom(): any {
    const placeholder = "hello"
    return placeholder 
}
```

```
cardValue: {Name: John, Size: Medium, Age: 34}
```

on the console.log for test 1-3 logs perfectly fine & as expected but when I change custom() to need the card value like so.

```
custom(): any {
  const placeholder = this.returnedData.cardValue] 
  return placeholder
}
```

test 3 returns undefined and gives me an error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cardValue')

I know that the issue is in custom function but I do not know what to change it to get it to work

Comment: Probably there was no incoming data yet at the point you attempt to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Following code runs before ngOnInit. this.returnedData is set in ngOnInit, and hence it throws error for this.returnedData.cardValue as returnedData is undefined.

```
cardDetails = [
    {
     cardValue: console.log('this is test 3, 'this.custom()),
    }
```

Change your custom code to as below. This will ensure if returnedData is not set, placeholder is empty otherwise card value of returned data.

```
const placeholder = this.returnedData? 
this.returnedData.cardValue : '';
```

Comment: I see how this would remove the problem of undefined but when trying this out i have the issue where now an empty string is returned and it will not be updated after this first initial run.

Comment: what does it print in this console?  console.log('test1',this.returnedData);

Comment: It prints the cardValue dict in the 1st and 2nd console log tests

Comment: Why does it print twice? There's only one subscribtion & it should print only one time. Since your second incorrect returnedData is causing the problem in that case

Comment: ya that was a mistake i meant it prints once which is fine

Answer (score 0):

Issue of undefined is because of asyncronous thread of observeable please modify your custom() method by accepting an argument when data received

```
    ngOnInit(): any {
  this.Service.incomingData().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.returnedData = data;
    this.custom(this.returnedData.cardValue);
  });
} 


custom(value): any {
    const placeholder = value
    return placeholder 
}
```